# How to setup Qt Creator to work with CMake on Mac with Qt 4.7 SDK?

Tags: macos, qt4, build-process, cmake, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator 2.2.1 under MacOS X 10.6.8, standard MacOS X install for CMake 2.8.5 and Qt SDK version 1.1.2 released on June 21st (Qt 4.7.3 libraries).

My CMakeLists.txt fails in the find_package for Qt4 -- the second of the lines below:

```
set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /Applications/CMake 2.8-5.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules)
find_package (Qt4 REQUIRED HINTS /Users/myname/QtSDK)
```

I added the first just to make sure it knew where FindQt4.cmake lives, but same error either with or without that line.

The error from CMake is as follows:

```
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
     CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (find_package):
     Could not find a configuration file for package Qt4.

     Set Qt4_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for Qt4.
     The file will have one of the following names:

     Qt4Config.cmake
     qt4-config.cmake
```

I've done some finds in both the installed QtSDK location and the CMake directories, and there's no Qt4Config.cmake.  I did see in the CMake module directory -- FindQt4.cmake, Qt4ConfigDependentSettings.cmake, and UseQt4.cmake

According to [this page](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake%3aHow_To_Find_Libraries):

> The find_package() command will look in the module path for Find.cmake, 
>   which is the typical way for finding libraries. First CMake checks all directories in
>   ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}, then it looks in its own module directory 
>   /share/cmake-x.y/Modules/.
>   If no such file is found, it looks for Config.cmake or 
>   -config.cmake, which are supposed to be installed by libraries 
>   (but there are currently not yet many libraries which install them) and 
>   that don't do detection, but rather just contain hardcoded values for the 
>   installed library.

So it seems like FindQt4.cmake should find the Qt4 I'm hinting at its location -- so why is it even making it down to Qt4Config.cmake?  Anyone get this to work on Mac with those standard installs?

Answer (score 3):

The "find_package(Qt4..." command is very dependent on finding a qmake executable.  Is "qmake" on your path? Try something like

```
set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE "<actual location of qmake on your system>")
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
```

Edit: I meant to type QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE; and I did not grok your statement about CMAKE_MODULE_PATH at first.

Comment: This was driving me nuts. Thank you for the easy solution.