# Cross Compiling QT4 application using cmake

Tags: cmake, qt4, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile a QT4 application using CMake in an Ubuntu 18.04 machine.
The following are the relevant lines I used in CMakeLists.txt.

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/CrossPlatform/Qt-4.8.6/")
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 4.8.6 REQUIRED PATHS /opt/CrossPlatform/Qt-4.8.6/)
if(NOT Qt4_FOUND)
message(FATAL_ERROR "Package Qt4.8 not found")
endif()

SET(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})
```

On running cmake, I get the following error:

```
 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt4" (requested
  version 4.8.6) with any of the following names:

    Qt4Config.cmake
    qt4-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt4" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt4_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt4" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

How to correct it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658691/how-to-setup-qt-creator-to-work-with-cmake-on-mac-with-qt-4-7-sdk).

Comment: @squareskittles The link discusses a similar situation, but NOT cross compiling. The solution suggested there is to show the path to the qmake file. In my case, the qmake will be for the target platform and hence will not be useful while cross compiling in the host platform. In fact, it will not even run on host platform!